# Django import wizard using JSON

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I am trying to create a wizard to import several of a model in Django using JSON. I want to be able to:

1. go to a URL like `entries/import/` which will display a textfield
2. where I can paste in some JSON entries and hit submit
3. which will then bring me to step 2 of the wizard where I will be presented with a list of model forms
4. where upon inspecting/changing some data I can hit submit and have all the entries saved

It looks like I want to use a [Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) in conjunction with a [FormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/). I have steps 1 and 2 complete, but I can't figure out how to get all the models to be presented as forms on step 2 of the wizard.

I've come across [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) that shows where I might be able to convert the JSON to a FormSet, but I haven't been able to get it to work as of yet. Below is what I believe to be the relevant code. Can you help me figure out how to get the formset to be passed to **step2**?

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text', 'tags']

class ImportForm(forms.Form):
    json = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='JSON')

class ImportSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    entryFormSet = formset_factory(EntryForm)

FORMS = (
    ("step1", ImportForm),
    ("step2", ImportSelectionForm),
)

TEMPLATES = {
    "step1": "entries/json_form.html",
    "step2": "entries/entry_import_form.html",
}

class ImportWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        current_step = self.storage.current_step

        if current_step == 'step2':
            # Not getting here for some reason after submitting step1
            prev_data = self.storage.get_step_data('step1')
            json = prev_data.get('step1-json', '')

            models = serializers.deserialize("json", json)
            EntryFormSet = formset_factory(EntryForm)
            formset = EntryFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

            return self.initial_dict.get(step, {'formset': formset})

        return self.initial_dict.get(step, {})

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(revierse_lazy('entries:index'))
```

Comment: perhaps make going to step 2 a redirect to a specific url, where you add in the ID of the just-created models and display them. You only get to write one httpresponse and then send it. You also seem to have a typo: revierse_lazy

Comment: The intention is to not create the models until after submitting step2, so they won't have IDs during step2. I eventually want to allow the user to pick-and-choose which entries to create on step2, but figured the initial step would be to just create them all. I also would like to keep the URL clean. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `step` parameter passed to `get_form_initial` method instead of using `self.storage.current_step`. After testing I've noticed that `self.storage.current_step` contains previous step.

Also notice that for some reason `get_form_initial` is processed twice, once for previous and once for current step.

Comment: That helped get into the step2 condition in `get_form_initial`, but I am still not getting any forms on step2 though.